# Download files via PSFTP in powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have a script that need to download files from ftp directory. In this directory I have a couple of folders that i don't need and four .log files that need to be downloaded with this script:

```
# Import Custom PSFTP Module (PowerShell FTP).
Import-Module PSFTP

$FtpServer = "***.***.***.***"
$User = "USER"
$PWD = "****"
$Password =  ConvertTo-SecureString $Pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$FtpCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($User, $Password)
Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FtpCredentials -Server $FtpServer -Session MyFtpSession
$FtpSession = Get-FTPConnection -Session MyFtpSession
$ServerPath = "/sd0/"
$LocalPath  = "C:\ftp"
$fileList   = Get-FTPChildItem -Session $FtpSession -Path $ServerPath -Filter "*.log"
foreach ($element in $fileList ) {
 $filename = $ServerPath  + $element.name
 Get-FTPItem  -Session $FtpSession  -Path $filename -LocalPath $LocalPath
```

I have output:

```
ContentLength           : -1
Headers                 : {}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ResponseUri             : ftp://***.***.***.***/
StatusCode              : ClosingData
StatusDescription       : 226 Transfer complete

LastModified            : 1.1.0001 г. 00:00:00 ч.
BannerMessage           : 220 FTP server ready.

WelcomeMessage          : 230 Login OK

ExitMessage             : 221 Bye

IsFromCache             : False
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
ContentType             :
```

With no downloaded files in the local directory. In verbose mode it says:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://***.***.***.***/sd0/file1.log'" on target "".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://***.***.***.***/sd0/file2.log'" on target "".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://***.***.***.***/sd0/file3.log'" on target "".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://***.***.***.***/sd0/file4.log'" on target "".
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: _"Import Custom PSFTP Module"_ You should check the documentation for this module to be sure you are using it correctly, and if so, contact the creator for assistance.